# Snapping window floating in QGIS 3.4.1?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, toolbar

I tried to dock the snapping panel by double-clicking on top of the panel but it's still not docking with the main QGIS window.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Because you opened it via **Project > Snapping options...**

Close your floating window, right click on some empty toolbar area and under **Toolbars** activate **Snapping Toolbar** as shown below:

[image]

But note that the toolbar and the Snapping options partially show the same options, but the Snapping options (rsp. Project snapping settings) are well needed when turning to *Advanced Configuration*:

[image]

In this case you are able to set up snapping properties for each distinct layer:

[image]

Comment: I opened the snapping option through the project because through the toolbar it's not showing on screen although it's checked in.

Answer (score 4):

**To dock a floating toolbar**

Click on the end of the toolbar (see the circled area in the image below) and drag it to any side of the QGIS window until it snaps into place.

[image]

That toolbar will re-appear in the same place the next time you turn it off and back on again.

This allows you to customize the QGIS interface to your personal taste. Personally I like having the Manage Layers and Datasource Manager toolbars on the left side of the screen next to the Layers and Browser panels.